# zypper dependency resolution

Tags: dependencies, suse, zypper

I am facing problem while installing an "Company-hardening-1.0-1.noarch.rpm" RPM through zypper. There are 2 systems involved. Both are SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-Server-11-SP3 VMs.

System 1: (working)
In this system I am able to install the rpm, in this case, zypper is automatically resolving the dependency.

```
susevm1:~ # zypper install Company-hardening-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

The following NEW packages are going to be installed:
  Company-hardening openscap-engine-sce

The following packages are not supported by their vendor:
  Company-hardening openscap-engine-sce

2 new packages to install.
Overall download size: 195.0 KiB. After the operation, additional 1.0 MiB will be used.
Continue? [y/n/?] (y): n
```

System 2: (Not working)

In this system RPM is not getting installed, as zypper is not able to resolve the dependency.

```
linux-g33k:~/Desktop/RPMS # zypper install Company-hardening-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

Problem: nothing provides openscap-engine-sce >= 1.2.5-2 needed by Company-hardening-1.0-1.noarch
 Solution 1: do not install Company-hardening-1.0-1.noarch
 Solution 2: break Company-hardening-1.0-1.noarch by ignoring some of its dependencies

Choose from above solutions by number or cancel [1/2/c] (c): c
```

Note that, both system are having same version of zypper. I know, this might a simple and silly question. :) This might be because  of some repository diff.

Thanks,
Hemant

Answer (score 1):

It means you don't have the same repositories activated on both machines. Comparing the output of

```
zypper lr -u
```

on both machines should show you which repository to add or enable.